# Multilanguange with domaine

Tags: plugins, multi-language

I was trying a lot of different plugins, and was shocked that something so fundamental like multilanguage is not easily possible with wordpress - and if yes it cost ongoing money, not one time payment. Is this a joke?

Is there really no way to have multilanguage with specific domain query (mysite.com/en or mysite.com?lang=en) in wordpress? How are you guys doing it?

Comment: It's not something I've needed to do, but at first glance there are free versions of [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/), [Weglot](https://wordpress.org/plugins/weglot/), [TranslatePress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/translatepress-multilingual/), [WPGlobus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpglobus/) etc. and probably more I don't recognise. Just not WPML.

Comment: Generally though premium plugins won't stop working when you stop paying, you'll just stop getting updates. Which means they might stop working eventually if the WordPress internals change enough, and you might be stuck without a security update etc. But might not be disastrous for a small blog.

Comment: You can also set up independent sites in each language out of the box with WordPress multisite.

Comment: Thank you @Rup this comment was important: "they won't stop working, just because you stop paying." - Polylang is free, but you can't copy pages, you need to create the whole website (if you have 4 languages) again and again and copy by hand the content - and also the domain options are not available. I was hoping there is a "native" way to have multilanguage easily, so it must be a plugin?